# how to remove datetime from x-axis in chart control in c# window application

Tags: c#

I am working on a chart control in c# window application. i want to show data into chart control from sqlserver database of a daterange. For this I did following code in the database

```
chart2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

chart2.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yy HH:mm";
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1;
chart2.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;

chart2.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chart2.Series[0].XValueMember = "DateAndTime";
chart2.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Zone1_Temp";
chart2.Series[0].LegendText = "Zone1_Temp";
chart2.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;

chart2.Series[1].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chart2.Series[1].XValueMember = "DateAndTime";
chart2.Series[1].YValueMembers = "Zone2_Temp";
chart2.Series[1].LegendText = "Zone2_Temp";
chart2.Series[1].Color = Color.Blue;

chart2.Series[2].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chart2.Series[2].XValueMember = "DateAndTime";
chart2.Series[2].YValueMembers = "Zone3_Temp";
chart2.Series[2].LegendText = "Zone3_Temp";
chart2.Series[2].Color = Color.Yellow;

chart2.Series[3].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chart2.Series[3].XValueMember = "DateAndTime";
chart2.Series[3].YValueMembers = "Zone4_Temp";
chart2.Series[3].LegendText = "Zone4_Temp";
chart2.Series[3].Color = Color.Cyan;

chart2.Series[4].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chart2.Series[4].XValueMember = "DateAndTime";
chart2.Series[4].YValueMembers = "Zone5_Temp";
chart2.Series[4].LegendText = "Zone5_Temp";
chart2.Series[4].Color = Color.Pink;
```

I have a button on which i wrote the above code. I gave the date range from '15-11-2021 15:35:27' to '16-11-2021 15:35:27' and Chart is showing data as following
[image]

There is no data between '15-11-2021 18:20:14' and '16-11-2021 10:55:16' but the hours between these  hours are still showing in the x-axis which should not be shown. how to solve this?

Comment: Can you please share if you're working in winforms, wpf, uwp, etc because the solution may be drastically different

Comment: This reminds me of a DailyWTF post...but I cant find it. Can't you just extract the common pattern and update in a loop?

Comment: @Anthony Russell I have already mentioned above I am working on an c# winforms application

Comment: @SunnySandeep please reread your post because no where in there do you say winforms. You say ` c# window application` which can be a number of things